# Getting two analog video channels out of a Pi 4B or 3B

Tags: hdmi, composite-video

It is correct to assume that with the Pi 4B's two HDMI outputs, it is possible, using two HDMI-to-RCA analog video adapters, to supply two analog CRT monitors with independent signals from the same computer? Like two PAL signals? The signal I need I guess is called 576i (standard PAL TV screen signal), on a composite RCA or SCART.

Like using two of these type of adapters which select PAL output and take 1080p or 720p input:

[image]

And would this also be possible with a Pi 3B, combining its analog output with an adapter on its HDMI output?

(Sound is not needed)

Comment: the pi doesn't care what happens to the signal once it leaves the pi into this `HDMI-to-RCA analog video adapters` - but no, you can't have both analog and HDMI output on the pi3+/3/2/1

Comment: @JaromandaX would you mind posting that as an answer then? I edited the question to include the type of adapter I imagine to use with both HDMI outputs of the Pi 4.

Comment: Anecdotal experience with the RPI4 was that an HDMI to VGA adaptor would work on one hdmi port but not reliably well enough to use on the second one.

Comment: @Charemer I have been using dual screen with HDMI-VGA adapter on the second port without problems for more than 6 months. Perfectly reliable.

Comment: @Dirk - I don't disbelieve, that's why I said 'anecdotal'.  Purely my own limited experience with RPi4 and HDMI to VGA - could've easily been a monitor or adaptor or cable issue.

Answer (score 1):

I used two of those adapters and could get two independent analog video signals to work (Pi 4B).